# How do I implement a C++ virtual pure class in C#?

Tags: c++, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

Hello Stackoverflow community !

I'm trying to interop in a C# program with a very old dll written in C++ and I'm facing a very big issue:

- my C++ DLL exposes a method getPlugin with the following signature:

  ```
  extern "C" Plugin* getPlugin();
  ```
- with the definition of Plugin:

  ```
  virtual void onLoad(Service* service) =  0;
  virtual const char *getDescription()const = 0;
  ```
- the definition of the class Service :

  ```
  virtual void getLongValueConf(const char *section, const char*key,long *output_value ) = 0;
  ```
- the implementation of the method `getDescription` :

  ```
  const char* MyClass::getDescription() const
  {
      static char  buffer[512];
      sprintf(buffer, "FOO");
      return loc_tc_buffer;
  }
  ```
- the implementation of the method `onLoad` that calls the method `getLongValueConf` :

  ```
  void MyClass::onLoad(Service* service)
  {
      _service = service;
      _service->getLongValueConf("FOO", "BAR",(long*) &_value);
  }
  ```
- So I implement in my C# program :

  - A static wrapper that contains the entry point:

    ```
    public static class Wrapper
    {
        [DllImport("MyCppDll.dll", EntryPoint= "getPlugin", CallingConvention= CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet= CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping= false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar= true)]
        public static extern IntPtr getPlugin();
    }
    ```
  - An implementation of the Plugin class that contains a struct which correspond to the vtable:

    ```
    public class Plugin
    {
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate void onLoadCb(IntPtr service);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate IntPtr getDescriptionCb();

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PluginVtbl
        {
            public IntPtr onLoad;
            public IntPtr getDescription;
        }
    }
    ```
  - An implementation of the Service class

    ```
    public class Service
    {
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate void getLongValueConf(char[] section, char[] key, ref int output_value);
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct ServiceVtbl
        {
            public IntPtr getLongValueConf;
        }
    }
    ```
  - The internal class to call the methods onLoad and getDescription :

    ```
    public static class Loader
    {
        private static IntPtr serverPointer;
        private static IntPtr vtable;
        private static PluginVtbl handle;
        private static IntPtr servicePointer;
        public static void Load(ServiceVtbl service)
        {
            serverPointer = SSI_getServerPlugin();
            vtable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(serverPointer, 0);
            handle = (PluginVtbl)Marshal.PtrToStructure(vtable, typeof(PluginVtbl));
            onLoadCb func = (onLoadCb)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(handle.onLoad, typeof(onLoadCb));
            servicePointer = new IntPtr();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ServiceVtbl));
            servicePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(service, servicePointer, false);
            func(servicePointer);
        }
        public static string GetDescription()
        {
            serverPointer = SSI_getServerPlugin();
            vtable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(serverPointer, 0);
            handle = (PluginVtbl)Marshal.PtrToStructure(vtable, typeof(PluginVtbl));
            getDescriptionCb func = (getDescriptionCb)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(handle.getDescription, typeof(getDescriptionCb));
            IntPtr pointerTemp = func();
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pointerTemp);
        }
    }
    ```
  - And then, my program implementation:

    ```
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Server.GetDescription());
            ServiceVtbl table = new ServiceVtbl();
            getLongValueConf delgetLongValueConf = new getLongValueConf(getLongValueConf);

            table.getLongValueConf = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delgetLongValueConf);

            Server.Load(table);
        }

        static void getLongValueConf(char[] section, char[] key, ref int output_value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", section, key);
        }
    }
    ```

When I call `Console.WriteLine(Server.GetDescription());` my output is 'FOO'.
But I have an AccesViolationException when I call `Server.onLoad` method. So I decided to check the addresses of my different pointers and I notice that the `servicePointer` in my C# code do not have the same address as the `service` pointer in the C++ code.

Does anyone has a solution ?

**EDIT: Stack Trace**
void Main(string args[])
.Server.Load(table)
..func(servicePointer)
...void MyClass::onLoad(Service* service) **CPP Side**
...._service->getLongValueConf("FOO", "BAR",(long*) &_value) **Access Violation**

Thank you!

Olivier.

Comment: Marshalling pointers between processes is futile and does not make sense.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite : actually, the method getLongValueConf is called in my C++ DLL and I want to handle it in my C# program.

Comment: In that case you should be more clear what you want to do. Marshalling has a specific meaning and that **seems** not to be the right term. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well... my bad... I just edit my question, can you please tell me if I forgot something ?

Comment: Surely the argument you pass to onLoad() is bad.  Two basic reasons for that: you are helping too much, you should pass serverPointer instead.  And the CallingConvention of the delegate might be wrong, good odds it is stdcall, apply the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand what you mention about the  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] because I already use it. And I have other method that I call with the StdCall and it works quite well so ... I don't know what can I test.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Do you still consider my question as not-understandable ?

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found why I can't share memory between my C# Program and my C++ DLL... I will probably write a C++ wrapper that exposes explicitely my callbacks.

Does anyone has ever face this issue ?